# Sql power architect to compare two data models

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need to compare the current data model with the old data model.

I am using sql power architect for it to do the comparison, I can able to configure the connections for accessing the database, where the connection is successful.

(I am using amazon redshift DB as the source for this.)

But when I tried to expand the children, i am getting the list of table objects associated with it and when I tried to do a compare datamodel option, I am seeing the below error.

Help me to resolve the same.

> Caused by: ca.sqlpower.sqlobject.SQLObjectException:
>   relationship.populate     at
>   ca.sqlpower.sqlobject.SQLRelationship.fetchExportedKeys(SQLRelationship.java:740)
>     at
>   ca.sqlpower.sqlobject.SQLTable.populateRelationships(SQLTable.java:731)
>     at ca.sqlpower.sqlobject.SQLTable.populateImpl(SQLTable.java:1337)
>     at ca.sqlpower.sqlobject.SQLObject.populate(SQLObject.java:186)     ...
>   4 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to
>   determine a value for MaxIndexKeys due to missing system catalog data.
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getMaxIndexKeys(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:64)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getImportedExportedKeys(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:3196)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getExportedKeys(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:3584)
>     at
>   ca.sqlpower.sql.jdbcwrapper.DatabaseMetaDataDecorator.getExportedKeys(DatabaseMetaDataDecorator.java:388)
>     at
>   ca.sqlpower.sqlobject.SQLRelationship.fetchExportedKeys(SQLRelationship.java:735)
>     ... 7 more

Answer (score 0):

you are using the wrong version of JDBC .
please follow the below steps
- download the JDBC driver from AWS redshit from AWS website.
- configure the JDBC driver part in sql power architect from connection manager.
- go to JDBC driver -> select postgres -> in add jars configure the jar downloaded -> configure the driver class name - click OK
- now go back to connection manager 
- select the appropriate connection and select edit and test for connection
- you can see the downloaded jar configured 
- now you can add the data object to sql power architect.